# How to blur last lines of text if it is not fit into TextView

Tags: android

I need to implement the following mockup.

[image]

As you can see, if text is not fit into TextView, it has blurred last lines

For this purpose I added necessary attributes to the TextView:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_expandable_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/volte_medium"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/info_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_text_size_14"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_merchant_conditions_title"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem/random" />
```

But the text in TextView looks like this:

[image]

So, can you please help me and explain what I do wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try keeping the text for Ver todo in a new text view and then apply paddingTop as you require and then apply a gradient drawable which has partly transparent gradient on top and white color as end color.

A sample gradient is mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#00FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

Apply this gradient as background to the textView for the Ver todo text

```
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
```

This should work fine.

Comment: How does startColor differ from endColor?

Comment: Hi @CoolMind, I have improved my code. That should be the start and end colors. It was a copy-paste error

Comment: Also we should create a more complicated view structure. Overlap a gradient view over `TextView` and set sizes.